# Creating a raised note on tableau data label

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to create note markers next to my labels in tableau.  The end user would like the suffix note numbers 1, 2, 3 be raised just like they are in text books.

Label a = Label a1 with the one be Superscript.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Comment: I don't believe you can add subscript or superscript to labels. The closest you could come would be to type a number and change the font size to something smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no direct way to achieve this but in future Tableau might implement it - https://community.tableau.com/ideas/5805

**Workaround:**
If you type in **Unicode Character** along with normal characters then you can have subscript as well as superscript in your dashboard. In Windows

- press Win+R and type in `charmap` to open 'Character Map' popup
- scroll down and look for numbers which can be used as superscript in your use case and copy it
- then go to text box of a dashboard in Tableau desktop and paste it.

Voila!

Comment: Thanks, ended up convincing them to go with Asterisks instead.